# Hashing a string in PHP in the same way as in VB.NET

Tags: php, vb.net, hash, sha256

I have following encryption function and don't know in which language this code is written. as per my knowledge this function is encrypting string in SHA256.

```
Use Namespace: Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Data: Agent Code ~ Userid ~ Security ID~ MerchantID~ Terminalid~ LoginKey
Public Function EncryptSHA(ByVal Data As String) As String
Dim sh As New SHA256Managed
Try
Convert.ToBase64String(sh.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data)))
Dim eNC_data As Byte() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data)
Dim eNC_str As String = Convert.ToBase64String(eNC_data)
Return eNC_str
Catch ex As ExceptionGeneral.Err_Handler("General", "EncryptSHA", ex.Message)
Return Nothing
End Try
End Function
```

I am working on php and want same php encryption function in php . 
Please someone explain what encryption this function is using ??
Here is my php code :

```
$data='Agent Code ~ Userid ~ Security ID~ MerchantID~ Terminalid~ LoginKey';
$encryptcode = hash('SHA256', $data);
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This is VB.Net. It is important you use the right encoding when you try to decrypt the data in php. (Ascii). Maybe you should post you php code as well?

Comment: @Merryweather php code added , please help

Comment: SHA256 and all cryptographic hash functions are **not encryption**, they are one-way functions, the original data can not be obtained. Since they can not be reversed they are not encryption which can be reversed to obtain the original data. Terminology does matter.

Answer (score 0):

SHA256 is a hash function and that's a oneway enryption. There is no way to decrypt it. The whole purpose of a cryptographic hash function is that you can't reverse it. It is used for example to verify a users password: Compare the hash of a users password with the hash saved in the database, to verify a users identity.

If you want to break it you can try these techniques:

1. Brute force
2. Rainbow tables

Comment: i don't want to decrypt it , i want to make same encryption fuction in php

Comment: I see, please make that clear in your post what you are trying to do.